# Retrieving Traffic counts

Tags: here-api

Is there an API that gives the traffic count for a given day on a particular road?

I have tried the Traffic Flow API but that only gives the Speed, Jam factor, Free flow on the stretch.

I tried this API:

> https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxx&bbox=12.980750,77.598090;12.990750,77.628090&responseattributes=sh,fc

```
"CF": [
                                    {
                                        "TY": "TR",
                                        "SP": 24,
                                        "SU": 27.29,
                                        "FF": 27,
                                        "JF": 0,
                                        "CN": 0.73
                                    }
                                ]
```

But that doesn't tell me the number of vehicles on the road. If there is any such API please do point me to it.

Comment: Could you describe your use case? May be different solution would be possible

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no such API.